# android handle selector state

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using following code to load an image from internal memory to tab icons. Images are loaded properly for state_enabled but no change when state_selected. What I am doing wrong? thank you.

```
ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        File imgFile = new  File("data/data/"+PACKAGE_NAME+"/biblioteca/" + imageName);
        File imgFileSel = new  File("data/data/"+PACKAGE_NAME+"/biblioteca/" + imageName);

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(myBitmap);

        Bitmap myBitmapSelected = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFileSel.getAbsolutePath());
        Drawable dSel = new BitmapDrawable(myBitmapSelected);

        StateListDrawable selector = new StateListDrawable();
        selector.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_enabled }, d);
        selector.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_selected }, dSel);
        icon.setImageDrawable(selector);}
```

xml gives an alert "missing content description"

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"

    />
```

Comment: can you post complete xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`state_pressed` help you...

and

```
missing content description
```

ant its just Lint error checking ....Its doesnt make differ,,,

Comment: thanks for alert explanation! state_pressed added but still not working!

Answer (score 0):

```
StateListDrawable selector = new StateListDrawable();
selector.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_pressed }, dSel);
selector.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_focussed }, dSel);
selector.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_enabled }, d);
selector.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_selected }, dSel);
icon.setImageDrawable(selector);
```

Try it also refer to this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)

Comment: Made a minor change now try it and what exactly you are doing can you explain i breif....